# Как по значению свойства объекта найти сам объект в List

Tags: c#, linq, list, vb.net

Подскажите как современными средствами быстро найти нужный объект в `List`

Имеется `List(Of ExDatabase)`

Известно, что в свойстве `DataBase` одного из объектов в списке имеется например "databaseTest".
Как быстро (одной строчкой если это возможно) получить сам объект?

Код класса `ExDatabase`

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing.Design


<Serializable()>
Public Class ExDatabase

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub


    Private _database As String

    <DisplayName("Имя базы")>
    <TypeConverter(GetType(DatabaseListConverter))>
    Public Property DataBase() As String
        Get
            Return _database
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _database = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _table_prefix As String

    <DisplayName("Префикс таблиц")>
    Public Property TablePrefix() As String
        Get
            Return _table_prefix
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _table_prefix = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Class DatabaseListConverter
        Inherits DbStringConverter

        Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesSupported(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function
        Public Overrides Function GetStandardValuesExclusive(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetStandardValues(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As StandardValuesCollection

            Return GetShowDatabases()

        End Function

    End Class



End Class
```

> P.S. Естественно я понимаю что можно пройтись циклом по списку,
>   сравнить значения и найти объект.

Comment: если только один: [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx), если несколько [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: мне это ни о чем не говорит...

Comment: Это методы `Linq`, которые возвращают один или несколько объектов удовлетворяющих условию, по предоставленным ссылках есть примеры использования этих методв

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim db As ExDatabase = databaseList.First(Function(item) item.DataBase = "databaseTest")
```